# Control flow "skips" an execute SQL task

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, ssis-2012, control-flow

In the package, the first EST provides a filename from a table and a script task checks for its existence.  Expression tasks set an appropriate message, wish is sent to second EST to update table with the new message.  However, the second Execute SQL Task is neither validated or executed.  The sql is supposed to update a table and is parameterized to provide text for the table, but execution of the package just seems to stop at the task and the Execution Results have nothing regarding the task and no obvious error messages appear.  If the task is executed on its own, it gets a green check mark and the table is updated correctly.  Any ideas on what's going on?

[image: Control Flow after execution]

Comment: I forgot to include, this is VS 2010, on SQL 2012 server.

Answer (score 0):

Your second EST is waiting for both Precedence Contraints to complete before executing. I'm guessing that only one of the "Set File (not) Exists Msg" tasks will ever run. If this is the case, your second EST will never execute because one of the two Precedence Contraints will never evaluate.

The solution is to have two copies of the second EST, and have each "Set File (not) Exists Msg" link to its own copy of the EST.

Comment: Thank you digital.aaron.  I have modified as you suggested!

Answer (score 0):

Just click on one of the precedence constraints (arrows) linked to the Task you want to execute and check the `Logical Or` option.

[image]